# Convert PG_query to PDO statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, pdo

I'm a bit lost with this statement. I am trying to convert this PG_query script into PDO. The Idea is that I can then use this example, to pull other values from the database and display in a form.I can populate a dropdown with the PDO but wasn't sure what to do so I can grab row values and fill form items. So this example I just want to grab rivername.

```
$result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM rivers_tbl WHERE river_id  = '$river_id'");
$test = pg_fetch_array($result);
  if (!$result) 
    {
    die("Error: Data not found..");
    }
    $rivername = $test['rivername'];
```

**I have a DB connection working and this part of my query in PDO**

```
 $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM rivers_tbl WHERE river_id  = '$river_id'");
   if ($stmt2->execute()) {
       $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }
```

Comment: came across this just now [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: yes, very good tutorial for PDO and prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rivers_tbl WHERE river_id  = :river_id";
    $sth = $conn -> prepare($sql);
    $sth -> bindValue(':river_id', $river_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth -> execute();

    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if (!$sth) { 
    die("Error: ..");
    }
    $rivername = $row['rivername'];
```

In this example I use Error executing the query, but for something like records not found use:

```
if ($count = $sth->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo "No records Found!";
}else{
    $rivername = $row['rivername'];
}
```